# C++ in QT: changing opacity buttons and labels

Tags: c++, qt

I would like the make my buttons transparent, so that the user doesn't see them but only the background. Whenever I however set the opacity to 0, or change the background color. It does only change the edges. See image 1 (The middle button has a the stylesheet applied).

[image]

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setStyleSheet("background-image:url(:/images/gui_main.png)");

    ui->alrm_dwn->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);");

    connect(ui->alrm_dwn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(change_dwn()));
    connect(ui->alrm_up, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(change_up()));
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement custom buttons as underlying images with transparent QButtons on top of them?

Comment: whats the question....?

Comment: I would just create a new Q_OBJECT widget that acts as a button, and apply whatever stylesheet you wanted, and then just send a signal by overriding the MouseButtonPress method. Much cleaner than stacking buttons.

Comment: I have tried that. But it stil gives the same result. In the picture above is just a .png file as background using stylesheet of a mainwindow. with on top of that 3 buttons and a label. My question is, how can I get rid of the strange blue color that the buttons keep having. When I set the opacity of the buttons to 0 it only changes the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer, if you set the background of an widget using stylesheet like i did. All the object in the widget get the same background apparently.